# Tracking "conversation" flow in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, api, cookies, sinatra, rack

Consider [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/tracking-conversations) post. I'm dealing with  messaging API, however it's not the Twilio API. The server in question has no explicit support for storing cookies so I'm wondering how I can store the session state/data either in memory, on my server or in a database somehow.

Is it as simple as using `Rack::Session::Pool` as the cookie method? I can't find any good tuts or examples.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mix up cookies and sessions a bit.

**cookies**

A cookie, also known as an HTTP cookie, web cookie, or browser cookie, is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website. [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

This mean there are small text files on client site with information in it. This mean it's maybe not the best idea to save sensitive content in clear text. And you must be aware, that it's in client hand if it accept cookies.

In sinatra they are built in but named session (I know, a bit confusing, this is because cookies are Client side web sessions)

Example code

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :sessions

get '/' do
  session["value"] ||= "Hello world!"
  "The cookie you've created contains the value: #{session["value"]}"
end
```

And there is Sinatra::Cookies in [Sinatra Contrib](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies.html). I have no clue why this even exist, but it worth mentioning.

**Session**

Sessions or explicit Server side web sessions is a state for each client which is hold on server site.

Example code

```
require 'sinatra'
use Rack::Session::Pool

get '/' do
  session["value"] ||= "Hello world!"
  "The server side session you've created contains the value: #{session["value"]}"
end
```

**Conclusion & TL;DR**

Without knowing what you exactly try to achieve, it's hard to tell which will work better for you. Additionally there is even possible to combine both and save the state to a Database. So it depend on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. I think I was mixing them up a bit. Basically just trying to do the same thing as in the Twilio blog post, but with a server that doesn't explicitly accept cookies to store session state, so I need to store the session state on my side to keep track of the conversation flow. Thanks again.